# Are the Icom 2300 h and Ftm 400dr DC cables interchangable?

Tags: mobile, dc-power

I would like to swap out my 2300h to a 400dr. Would rather not swap out dc power cable. Are the cables the same or is there an adapter for make it possible?

Comment: Hi Rich, welcome to Amateur Radio StackExchange. Have you consulted the manuals for the 2300H and 400DR? A quick Google search for "ICOM 2300H manual", for example, leads to ICOM's website where all the manuals are available for download.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the cables for both the IC-2300 H and the FTM-400DR are both plasic "T" connectors and so it is possible to swap out the radios without changing the power cables.

The [JetStream JTPC-33M 9.5’ "T" Connector Power Cord](http://www.randl.com/shop/catalog/product_info.php?cPath=15_8170&products_id=67399)
  works quite well.